# Can I add data to an incoming REST request in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently looking for a way to add additional data to a WordPress REST request directly when it reaches WordPress so that I can access the data "later" in each REST route callback.

I've tried to set it in the rest_pre_dispatch filter but it seems to be not correct:

```
add_filter( 'rest_pre_dispatch', [ $this, 'filter_rest_pre_dispatch' ], 10, 3 );
public function filter_rest_pre_dispatch( $result, WP_REST_Server $server, WP_REST_Request $request ) {
    $request->set_attributes( [
        'test' => '1'
    ] );

    return $result;
}
```

Has anyone done this before and might help me out?

Comment: `set_attributes` replaces all of the existing attributes with what you provide, so I'd think you also want to combine that with an `array_merge` and a call to `get_attributes` on the request. Otherwise, if you are "filling in the blanks" on the request, using the `*_param` methods might be an option, too

Comment: @ChrisHaas that would be the next step but it's not replacing anything at the moment. In the route handler the attributes are still the same even with my little test replace...

Comment: Okay, I apologize for asking, but my next question is are you sure this function is actually being hit? Have you thrown some debug code in here to make sure?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Yes, my function get's triggered successfully. Verified it with `error_log()`.

Comment: Coffee is starting to kick in now. I think (assume) that WP wants to keep the request as close to the original as possible for debugging reasons. One rogue plugin "fixing" the data could cascade like crazy. So I think your options are limited using the sanitization callback to "tweak" the data, or just using the normal callback which should have the same logic that is available in the pre_ hook

Comment: You could try `rest_request_after_callbacks` or `rest_request_before_callbacks` and methods of the request object like `$request->get_attributes()` and `$request->set_attributes()`

Comment: `$request->set_body_params()` would also allow you to manipulate and add additional data to the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've still found no solution for this. Instead I've created an abstract class which extends every class to register an endpoint and its function. In this abstract class I'm doing this for example to get a consumer key:

```
/**
 * Returns the consumer key from the current request
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function get_request_consumer_key(): string {
    $consumer_key = '';

    if ( ! empty( $_GET['consumer_key'] ) ) {
        $consumer_key = sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_GET['consumer_key'] ) );
    }

    if ( empty( $consumer_key ) && ! empty( $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] ) ) {
        $consumer_key = sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] ) );
    }

    return consumer_key;
}
```

Thats the only solution in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You could try filter such as `rest_request_after_callbacks` or `rest_request_before_callbacks` and methods of the request object like `$request->get_attributes()` and `$request->set_attributes()` to change the REST endpoint arguments

Also `$request->set_body_params()` would allow you to manipulate and add additional data to the request